# Why are tensorflow sessions and graph so difficult to understand?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow, and need to use some legacy code to finish a project. I use PyTorch before. I feel so difficult to understand TensorFlow. I use 1.14.0 version.
1. I use Jupyter Notebook. When I create some operations, sometimes I need to same cell multi times due to debug. Then I find it my graph is very weird. What happened when I run these cells which create some ops in the graph multi times? It cause my confusion about graph and sessions. From my current understanding, I need to build a static graph to run code. So what the purpose of sessions? When I in Jupyter, I find something wrong and edit the runned code, do I need to reset the graph and sessions?
2. Debug is a disaster. When there is something wrong with the dimension. Tensorflow has some long complains but never tell me why go wrong. I need to look carefully to find out out errors.
3. It seems API has changed greatly. I always recieved some warning, these interfacees has be degraded.
4. Print something is hard. I need to call `sess.run` to get a list. Or add `tf.summary` op in the graph to run and see it in tensorboard.

I am deal with those old code. What is the correct way to use Tensorflow? I love the convinence brought by PyTorch. I can set some breakpoint and print anything I need easily. I want to do the samething with Tensorflow. Debugin Tensorflow waste me so much time. Is this true that only utils I flush my graph and open tensorboard can I see my computation graph? It is really unconvinient.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Though early versions of TensorFlow are hard to use, TensorFlow 2.0 is much better and has moved towards more dynamic graphs with features like AutoGraph. So don't be discouraged to use TensorFlow.

> 1. I use Jupyter Notebook. When I create some operations, sometimes I need to same cell multi times due to debug. Then I find it my graph is very weird. What happened when I run these cells which create some ops in the graph multi times? It cause my confusion about graph and sessions. From my current understanding, I need to build a static graph to run code. So what the purpose of sessions? When I in Jupyter, I find something wrong and edit the runned code, do I need to reset the graph and sessions?

Graph is the computational graph you build. TensorFlow uses GraphDef format to represent the graph. Essentially when you write,

```
tf_a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
tf_b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

tf_c = tf_a + (2.0 * tf_b)
```

TensorFlow builds the following graph in the background.

```
           tf_a     tf_b     tf_constant(2)
               \        \    /
                \        tf.mul
                 \      /
                  tf.add
                    |
                   tf_c
```

It just sits there and does not execute anything. That's why if you try to run print(tf_c) you won't see anything.

The session goes in, looks at the graph and execute bits and pieces of that graph. For example, when you say `sess.run(tf_c, feed_dict={tf_a:2.0, tf_b: 3.0})`. The session manager will look at the graph, understand that you need to feed values to both `tf_a` and `tf_b` to successfully evaluate `tf_c` and check if those values are provided and continues to execute the graph and fetch `tf_c`.

And if you want to rerun your code without blowing up your computational graph, you should use `tf.reset_defualt_graph()` at the beginning of the cell. This will clean up the graph. Otherwise, you will keep adding items to the graph and even end up with errors (e.g trying to create a variable with same name twice).

Having said that TensorFlow 2.0 is much better. TensorFlow 2.0 has got rid of the concept of sessions and immediately executes things as you call them.

> 2. Debug is a disaster. When there is something wrong with the dimension. Tensorflow has some long complains but never tell me why go wrong. I need to look carefully to find out out errors.

Can't say much here. But when you get used to it, it gets easier (at least that's my personal experience).

However, in TensorFlow 2.0 you can debug in real time using a preferred debugger, as operations and tensors are executed immediately as they are called.

> 3. It seems API has changed greatly. I always recieved some warning, these interfacees has be degraded.

Yes, TensorFlow is evolving quite rapidly. And did went though some major design changes over the years.

> 4. Print something is hard. I need to call sess.run to get a list. Or add tf.summary op in the graph to run and see it in tensorboard.

That's how TensorFlow was designed. The reason is that having a static graph requires less complexity than dynamically building the graph. If the graph was build dynamically it does have to parse pythonic syntax (e.g. For loops / while loops / if else conditions) to infer the flow of data. And on top of that make sure the graph doesn't grow abitarily large (e.g. expanding a for loop).

I'm sure there are performance differences as well. But I haven't tested nor competent enough to elaborate on that.

This is my take on your questions. Hope it clears things up.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It does clear things up. I guess that also explains why PyTorch is more popular in top AI conferences.